# Using <BaloonStyle> and <LableStyle> together

Tags: kml

I am new to KML and seem to be going round in circles. Hope someone can help.

I want to show a HTML balloon and get rid of the ugly driving directions. I am using 'BalloonStyle' to do this.

Also want to be able to hide the placemark label, so am using 'LabelStyle' to do this.

I can get these to work separately, but don't seem to be able to get them to work together to achieve the desired result.

Below is sample code which replicates the issue. Am I doing something wrong? Or do these two items just not work together? If so, is there another way to get the desired result (a HTML Balloon and a hidden label)?

Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Style id="randomLabelColor">
      <LabelStyle>
         <color>ff0000cc</color>
         <colorMode>random</colorMode>
        <scale>1.5</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
  </Style>

  <Style id="FEXBalloonStyle">
  <BalloonStyle>
     <bgColor>ffffff</bgColor>
     <text><![CDATA[<b><font color="#CC0000" size="+2">$[name]</font></b>
     <br><br/><font face="Courier">$[description]</font><br/><br/><br/><br/>]]></text>
     </BalloonStyle>  
  </Style>

  <Placemark>
    <name>LabelStyle.kml</name>

  <styleUrl>#randomLabelColor</styleUrl>
  <styleUrl>#FEXBalloonStyle</styleUrl>

  <Point>
     <coordinates>-122.367375,37.829192,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have *one* styleUrl for a Placemark.  If you want to have both the `<LabelStyle>` and `<BalloonStyle>` applied a single place mark, you have to put them in the same style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Style id="randomLabelColor">
  </Style>

  <Style id="FEXBalloonStyle">
    <LabelStyle>
      <color>ff0000cc</color>
      <colorMode>random</colorMode>
      <scale>1.5</scale>
    </LabelStyle>
    <BalloonStyle>
      <bgColor>ffffff</bgColor>
      <text><![CDATA[<b><font color="#CC0000" size="+2">$[name]</font></b>
      <br><br/><font face="Courier">$[description]</font><br/><br/><br/><br/>]]></text>
    </BalloonStyle>  
  </Style>

  <Placemark>
    <name>LabelStyle.kml</name>
    <styleUrl>#FEXBalloonStyle</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.367375,37.829192,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```