# Unable to bold in Google Earth Balloon Text

Tags: html, css, kml, google-earth

I'm trying to format text in a balloon on Google Earth using KML. I'm unable to get the text to be bold no matter which html/css tricks I try. The example below demonstrates that I'm able to format text as Arial Black, but applying `font-family:'Arial Bold'` has no effect. The `<b>` tag also doesn't work. Not shown in the example, I've also tried `<strong>` and`font-weight:bold`.

This screenshot shows how the code below is rendered in Google Earth. The text "Unformatted Text" has the same font weight as the text "Arial Bold" and "b tag", which should be bold. However, the "Arial Black" text is rendered in Arial Black as expected.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Format Test</name>
    <Style id="test-style">
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text>
          <p style="font-family:'Arial Black';">Arial Black</p> 
          <p style="font-family:'Arial Bold';">Arial Bold</p> 
          <p>This text has a <b>b tag</b></p>
          <p>Unformatted Text</p>
        </text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Test Placemark</name>
      <description><![CDATA['test']]></description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>
          -76.0,40.0,0
        </coordinates>
      </Point>
      <styleUrl>#test-style</styleUrl>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Your HTML is entity encoded, have you tried it with actual HTML tags? Related question/example: [Using <BaloonStyle> and <LableStyle> together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554016/using-baloonstyle-and-lablestyle-together)

Comment: I've updated the question to remove entity encoding and include an image that highlights the issue I'm having with the font rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample KML seems to mostly work for me, even with the encodings, which should get decoded just fine in Google Earth. I got the balloons shown below... in Earth Pro v7 (left), and Earth for web v9 (right).

[image: screenshots of balloons with bold text]

That shows the `style="font-family:'Arial Black';"` and the `<b>` tag both resulting bold text. The `style="font-family:'Arial Bold';"`is not appearing bold, but I believe that's because 'Arial Bold' is an unusual font, and appears to only be supported by some browsers.

Maybe what you were looking for is the separate font-weight property, like this:

```
<p style="font-family:'Arial'; font-weight:'bold'">Arial font, bold weight</p>
```

I also noticed that you do not have the $[description] reference variable in your BalloonStyle/text tag, so your description text wasn't being included in the balloon.

In which version of Earth were you seeing the issue... can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I just updated the initial question with a screenshot. I tested this out in Google Earth Web and the <b> tag is rendering correctly. I'm using Google Earth 7.3.2.5491 on Mac OS X 10.14.2. I just tested from a PC and it renders correctly. It seems this is a bug in the Mac version of Google Earth, rather than an issue with code.

Comment: Yes, probably a difference in the web rendering engine used in the versions of Earth Pro for the different platforms (PC/Mac).  I believe they have been updating the rendering tools a lot over the past  year, so maybe there are updates yet to come which hopefully will make it consistent across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Related question/example: [Using `<BaloonStyle>` and `<LableStyle>` together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554016/using-baloonstyle-and-lablestyle-together)

You don't want the styles to be entity encoded. i.e.

```
&lt;p style="font-family:'Arial Black';"&gt; Arial Black &lt;/p&gt;
```

should be:

```
<p style="font-family:'Arial Black';"> Arial Black </p>
```

this should do what you expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Format Test</name>
    <Style id="test-style">
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<b><font size="+2">$[name]</font></b>
          <br/><br/><font face="Arial Black">$[description]</font><br/>
          <br/>Some other text<br/>
          <b>Some bold text</b><br/>]]>
        </text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Test Placemark</name>
      <description><![CDATA['test']]></description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>
          -76.0,40.0,0
        </coordinates>
      </Point>
      <styleUrl>#test-style</styleUrl>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: You're right that the entity encoding was unnecessary. However, if I open your KML in Google Earth the font face of "Some other text" and "Some bold text" is identical. The 'test' text is displayed in Arial Black correctly (as in my example), but my goal is to display Arial Bold or something equivalent.